# MongoConnect passing in client as the callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm confused about the callback here. We return the client in the promise, but how are we executing that in the callback? If the client object is the callback then isn't the client calling the client? What is the callback equivalent to?

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

const mongoConnect = callback => {
  MongoClient.connect(
    'mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0-ntrwp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true'
  )
    .then(client => {
      console.log('Connected!');
      callback(client);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

module.exports = mongoConnect;


(app.js)
mongoConnect(client => {
  console.log(client);
  app.listen(3000);
});
```

Isn't this the expected output. I'm a little confused about the callback here.

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

const mongoConnect = client => {
      console.log(client);
      app.listen(3000); => {
  MongoClient.connect(
    'mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0-ntrwp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true'
  )
    .then(client => {
      console.log('Connected!');
      client => {
        console.log(client);
        app.listen(3000);(client);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

module.exports = mongoConnect;


(app.js)
mongoConnect(client => {
  console.log(client);
  app.listen(3000);
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're asking how the 1st code works? What about the 2nd code? Is this a modification of the 1st code in a way that you think how it should be?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're asking how the 1st code works. I rewrote the 1st code to use old school `function()` instead of the ES6 fat arrow and put in some logging to make it clearer what's going on:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
const app = express();

function mongoConnect(callback) {
  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017')
    .then(client => {
      console.log('[mongoConnect] Connected!');
      console.log('[mongoConnect] callback type: ' + typeof(callback));
      console.log('[mongoConnect] client type: ' + typeof(client));
      console.log('[mongoConnect] client is: ' + client.constructor.name);
      callback(client);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

mongoConnect(function(client) {
  console.log('[main] client type: ' + typeof(client));
  console.log('[main] client is: ' + client.constructor.name);
  app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('[main] listening on 3000');
  });
});
```

Running the code:

```
[mongoConnect] Connected!
[mongoConnect] callback type: function
[mongoConnect] client type: object
[mongoConnect] client is: MongoClient
[main] client type: object
[main] client is: MongoClient
[main] listening on 3000
```

As to your question:

> If the client object is the callback then isn't the client calling the client? What is the callback equivalent to?

To unravel what's going on:

- `client` is an object, and `callback` is a function.
- `mongoConnect()` accepts a function as parameter.
- The function that gets passed into `mongoConnect()` accepts `client` (an object) as parameter. Technically this is not needed. I think this is only there for audit/logging purposes. You can remove all mentions of `client` in that part of the code and see that it still works.

For example, you can change that bit of code to be:

```
mongoConnect(function() {
  app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('[main] listening on 3000');
  });
});
```

and it will still work the same way.

The execution sequence is:

1. `mongoConnect(function(client))` is called
2. Inside `mongoConnect`, `MongoClient.connect()` is called
3. Once connected, the callback (`function(client)`) is called
4. The callback executes `app.listen()`

This flow sequence ensures that the database is connected before the app goes to listen mode. Without this, the app can listen before any database connection is confirmed (e.g. due to slower than expected database connection, etc.). You can confirm this flow by observing that `[mongoConnect]` log lines are always printed **before** any `[main]` log lines.